# How to put Text inside map function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to put a CusText component when growth Length Img is true. But when I put it in, an Unexpected Token error occurs.

So I put quotation marks or semicolons after the CusText component, but the same error occurs. How do I fix my code?

this is my code

```
{growthLengthImg[0] ? (

// <CusText />    << i want to put in here
growthLengthImg.map((v) => {
return(
<>
<Pressable>
<Image/>

</Pressable>
</>
)
})

) : (null)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide what `growthLengthImg[0]` data type. But with my guess, if it is empty text '', error will occur. For example,

```
const [text,setText] = useState("");

return (text ? <Text>{text}</Text> : <OtherComponent />);
```

To fix it, use `Boolean(text)` instead of `text`. Also, check some space, or dot in your component. Even a `.` or   (space), which is not inside `<Text>` component, can cause error.

Answer (score 0):

you can only return 1 component not 2

```js
  {growthLengthImg[0] ? (
            <>
              <CusText />
              {growthLengthImg.map((v) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Pressable>
                      <Image />
                    </Pressable>
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </>
          ) : null}
```